# How to have two control variables in a form

Tags: vba, excel

I have two select case's depending on .value condition if it's true or false. If the .value= true then use case without extend and else you case WITH extend everything seems to work however I am getting a for control variable already in use. How do I use multiple control variables? Please see code below

```
If onetimeoption.value = True Then

    Select Case MonthComboBox.value
        Case "Week One"
            iCol = "AY"

        Case "Week Two"
            iCol = "AZ"

        Case "Week Three"
            iCol = "BA"

        Case "Week Four"
            iCol = "BB"

        Case "Week Five"
            iCol = "BC"

        Case "Week Six"
            iCol = "BD"

        Case "One Seven"
            iCol = "BE"

        Case "One Eight"
            iCol = "BF"

        Case "One Nine"
            iCol = "BG"

        Case "One Ten"
            iCol = "BH"

        Case "One Eleven"
            iCol = "BI"

        Case "One Twelve"
            iCol = "BJ"
    End Select

Else



    nExtend = 1 'Set this as a default.
    Select Case MonthComboBox.value

        Case "Week One"
            iCol = "AY"
            nExtend = 12
        Case "Week Two"
            iCol = "AZ"
            nExtend = 11
        Case "Week Three"
            iCol = "BA"
            nExtend = 10
        Case "Week Four"
            iCol = "BB"
            nExtend = 9
        Case "Week Five"
            iCol = "BC"
            nExtend = 8
        Case "Week Six"
            iCol = "BD"
            nExtend = 7
        Case "One Seven"
            iCol = "BE"
            nExtend = 6
        Case "One Eight"
            iCol = "BF"
            nExtend = 5
        Case "One Nine"
            iCol = "BG"
            nExtend = 4
        Case "One Ten"
            iCol = "BH"
            nExtend = 3
        Case "One Eleven"
            iCol = "BI"
            nExtend = 2
        Case "One Twelve"
            iCol = "BJ"
            nExtend = 1
    End Select

End If

    actWarehouse = Me.WarehouseComboBox.ListIndex + 1

    With ws
        .Cells(irow, "A").value = Me.PartTextBox.value
        **For Each cel In .Cells(irow, iCol).Resize
        For Each cel In .Cells(irow, iCol).Resize(, nExtend)**
            cel.value = cel.value + CLng(Me.AddTextBox.value)
            cel.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        Next cel

        Next cel

    End With
```

Comment: `Next cel` line is repeated twice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use two for loops - just change the target variable name

Of course I don't know what you're trying to do with each cell - so check how you want to use cel1 and cel2 - I just guessed

```
 For Each cel1 In .Cells(irow, iCol).Resize

    For Each cel2 In .Cells(irow, iCol).Resize(, nExtend)
        cel1.value = cel2.value + CLng(Me.AddTextBox.value)
        cel1.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    Next cel2

 Next cel1
```